# Showing that the function defined as follows is a distance function, but not satisfies the triangle inequality.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

**Definition.** Let $S=\Bbb R^2=\{(x,y)\mid x,y \in \Bbb R\}$. Define a set of lines as follows: **A vertical line** is an arbitrary subset of $S$ of the form
$$L_a=\{(x,y) \in S \mid x=a\},$$
for some $a \in \Bbb R$. **A non-vertical line** is an arbitrary subset of $S$ of the form
$$L_{m,b}=\{(x,y) \in S \mid y=mx+b\},$$
for some real numbers $m$ and $b$.

**Definition.** A **distance function** on a set $\Bbb R^2$ is a function $d:\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ such that for all $P,Q \in \Bbb R^2$,

1. $d(P,Q) \ge 0$;
2. $d(P,Q)=0$ if and only if $P=Q$; and
3. $d(P,Q)=d(Q,P)$.

**Definition.** Let $B=\Bbb R^2$. Let $P=(x_1,y_1), Q=(x_2,y_2) \in B$. The **Euclidean distance**, denoted by $d_E$, is given by
$$d_E(P,Q)=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}.$$

**Definition.** A distance function $d$ on $\Bbb R^2$ satisfies the **triangle inequality** if
$$d(A,C) \le d(A,B)+d(B,C), \quad \text{for all} \ A,B,C \in \Bbb R^2.$$

**Definition.** Let $A,B \in \Bbb R^2$. A line that pass through $A$ and $B$ is defined by
$$L_{AB}=\{X \in \Bbb R^2 \mid X=A+t(B-A), \text{for some} \ t \in \Bbb R\}.$$

**EDIT.**

**Problem.**
Let $A=\Bbb R^2$. For any $P,Q \in A$, define a function $d_F:A \times A \to \Bbb R$ by
\begin{align*}
d_F(P,Q)=
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if} \ P=Q, \\
d_E(P,Q), &\text{if} \ L_{PQ} \ \text{is not vertical}, \\
3d_E(P,Q), &\text{if} \ L_{PQ} \ \text{is vertical}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

1. Prove that $d_F$ is a distance function on $A$.
2. Prove that $d_F$ is not satisfies the triangle inequality.

**Attempt:** Let $P=(x_1,y_1),Q=(x_2,y_2) \in A$.

1. First, we'll show that $d_F(P,Q) \ge 0$. If $P=Q$, then by definition of $d_F$, we have $d_F(P,Q)=0 \ge 0$. If $L_{PQ}$ is not vertical, then by definition, there exists real numbers $m$ and $b$ such that $L_{PQ}=L_{m,b}$. It means that $y_1=mx_1+b$ and $y_2=mx_2+b$.
   Hence,
   \begin{align*}
   d_F(P,Q) &= d_E(P,Q) \\
   &= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} \\
   &= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (mx_1+b-(mx_2+b))^2} \\
   &= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + m^2(x_1-x_2)^2} \\
   &= \sqrt{(1+m^2)(x_1-x_2)^2} \\
   &\ge 0.
   \end{align*}
   If $L_{PQ}$ is vertical, then there exists $a \in A$ such that $L_{PQ}=L_a$.
   It means that $x_1=x_2=a$. Hence,
   \begin{align*}
   d_F(P,Q) &=3 d_E(P,Q) \\
   &= 3\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} \\
   &=3 \sqrt{(a-a)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} \\
   &=3 \sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2} \\
   &\ge 0.
   \end{align*}
   Therefore, $d_F(P,Q)\ge 0$.

Second, we'll show that $d_F(P,Q)=0$ iff $P=Q$. But, it's clear by the definition of $d_F$.

Third, we'll show that $d_F(P,Q)=d_F(Q,P)$. This is also true and is easy to check.

Hence, $d_F$ is a distance function on $A$.

2. Choose $P=(1,1),Q=(2,2),R=(1,7) \in A$. Then $d_F(P,R) > d_F(P,Q) + d_F(Q,R)$. Hence, $d_F$ is not satisfies the triangle inequality.

Hence, proved. Q. E. D.

Any comments and corrections would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $d_E$ is a real valued function, and not $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued

Comment: @QED Sorry? What did you mean?

Comment: You said $d_F$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, but you define it using $d_E$ which is a function taking values in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @QED done. So, what's your opinion about my question?

Comment: Since $L_{PQ}$ is vertical implies $L_{QP}$ is vertical and since $d_E$ is itself a distance function, there was nothing much to show, other than that the triangle inequality does not hold for $d_F$, against which you have given a counterexample, so you did alright.

Comment: @QED basically, it's only use the fact that $d_E$ itself is a distance function, right? And because of that, all was very clear?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone not including the triangle inequality in the definition of a distance function before. It seems quixotic to me, as the triangle inequality is integral to the concept of "distance". You are certainly free to study positive definite symmetric functions that do not satisfy the triangle inequality, but I don't think it wise to use a term for it that is already widely used to mean something more specific. (Yes, I understand this isn't actually *your* terminology, but let me get my rant off my chest.)

Comment: As for your attempt. It works, but it wastes a lot of effort and calculation on matters that are not important. You already know $d_E(P, Q) \ge 0$ and $d_E(P,Q) = d_E(Q, P)$. All you needed to do is note that when $P \ne Q$, either $d_F(P,Q) = d_E(P,Q) \ge 0$ or $d_F(P,Q) = 3d_E(P,Q) \ge 0$. And on $d(P,Q) = d(Q,P)$, all you did was chant "that's obvious" when it is no more or less obvious than the first step where you spent so much effort.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot, Sir. :D